# A compile error that doesn't happen there but happens here

Tags: eclipse, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I will rename the title once I figure out what is going on.

Consider this code:

```
trait Tr {
    type A
}
type TrT[T] = Tr { type A = T }

def someFunc: Tr = ...

val tr = someFunc
val trt: TrT[tr.A] = tr
```

The official Scala libraries(2.11.1) with Eclipse(Kepler) compile and even run this code with no problem, while the SBT(0.13.5) with IntelliJ(13.1.3) throws an error on the last line, saying `tr` cannot be `TrT[tr.A]`. I put the dependency to the Reflection API in the `build.sbt` because I thought it should've been the cause, but it wasn't. Thus I'm stuck on this. Can anybody explain why this happens, and hopefully tell me how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: If you just compile it with sbt without Intellij, does it still throw an error?

Comment: Can you add the Sbt error message?

Comment: It works for me with Sbt 0.13.5 and the code you provided.

Comment: @johanandren No, it compiled. (I should have done this before asking the question :P) So the fact is in IntelliJ. I might have set the wrong compiler?

Comment: @IulianDragos So it seems the problem is not in SBT but IntelliJ or my settings on it. The error message is `Expression of type Tr doesn't conform to expected type TrT[tr.A]`.

Comment: IntelliJ does not use the Scala compiler for *errors-as-you-type*, so their type-checker might be slightly off. You could report a bug on the IntelliJ website.

Comment: @IulianDragos Yes I found it broken because it actually compiles while showing the error messages at the same time. I'm going to report this to them... Well thank you so much!